# Apollo client and on/offline events

Tags: javascript, offline, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am looking for this since last few days and almost pull all my hair off! Not even sure if its possible with apollo-client.

Is there a hook/pub-sub/event which I can use to know when the app becomes offline and when it comes online? I would have thought that because apollo handles those things internally, it would give something to hook into.

Just for my little poc, the fetch-policy is set to 'no-cache' and tried setting 'notifyOnNetworkStatusChange' both true and false but no luck.

So far I have tried following:

- use apollo-link-error : try using network error but its not firing.
- On `<Query ..>` : tried using OnError but its not firing
- On `<Query ..>` result: tried to use NetworkStatus but its either set to 1 or 7 neither helps.

Any help is much appreciated.

P

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? [Most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status) already support [events for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events).

Comment: My be this is because my lack of experience with apollo but a) we want to show status to the user that the app is offline which can be done easily by what you said and b) have a react-table component which doesnt behave very well in paged data. So what we want to do is that when the app becomes offline fetch data from cache if avail.

Comment: Sounds like for both you could [just use a hook](https://github.com/rehooks/online-status) and for the latter, just set the network policy accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to achieve this through 2 processes one as mentioned above use a browser event to check network availability, two, have your server return its online status by pinging it since your server could be down even when you have internet access.